# Airflow scheduler failure

Tags: celery, airflow-scheduler

I have followed
[this](https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html) tutorial in attempt to build an airflow cluster on localhost with my own DAGs. When I ran `airflow scheduler` after having set `executor = CeleryExecutor` in the config file, I received the following traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/bin/airflow", line 28, in 
>       args.func(args)
>
> File"/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 839, in scheduler job.run()
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 200, in run
>       self._execute()
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1309, in _execute
>       self._execute_helper(processor_manager)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1441, in _execute_helper
>       self.executor.heartbeat()
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/base_executor.py", line 124, in heartbeat
>       self.execute_async(key, command=command, queue=queue)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 80, in execute_async
>       args=[command], queue=queue)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 573, in apply_async
>       **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 354, in send_task
>       reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 310, in publish_task
>       **kwargs
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 172, in publish
>       routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 449, in _ensured
>       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 188, in _publish
>       mandatory=mandatory, immediate=immediate,
>
> File "/home/yurii/Tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librabbitmq/**init**.py", line 122, in basic_publish
>       mandatory or False, immediate or False,
>
> TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

Some additional information:

- I am using Airflow 1.8.0 along with Celery 3.1.25 and RabbitMQ 3.5.7 as a broker and backend, but also tried Airflow 1.9.0 with Celery 4.2.
- Airflow with sequential executor works without any problems.
- `airflow test "*dag_name*" "*task_name*" "*exec_date*" runs succeessfully.

I am new to Airflow/Celery/RabbitMQ/SQL, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using librabbitmq as amqp broker which is not recommended by celery core team. Use py-amqp as the rabbitmq broker and you should get rid of this error.

Comment: Shame they dont put this information in the docs or in the pip requirements at least. But thanks saved me a lot of pain.

Comment: @auvipy can you share a reference where the celery core team recommends pyamqp? The celery org on Github hosts both, librabbitmq and pyamqp. Moreover, they recommend librabbitmq in the "optimizing" section of their docs?! http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html

Comment: I myself is a celery core team member!!! btw you can check the readme of librabbot

Answer (score 4):

To add to previous answer. Using py-amqp involves either changing from `broker_url = amqp://XXXXX` to `broker_url = pyamqp://XXXXX` OR
`pip uninstall librabbitmq`.

Additionally you may need to change `celery_result_backend` variable to `result_backend` in your `airflow.cfg`. The `celery_` prefix has been removed for variables in the `[celery]` node in `airflow.cfg` in recent versions.

Comment: you're a savior. Thanks